# How to convert string to location like google maps in android

Tags: android, google-maps, gps

In Google maps or map quest or whatever mapping service website/app, we can usually put the address (which is in String format) and the website/app converts it to a location and show it to us on the map. My question is, how can I make it so that when the user puts in a string for their location(most likely a zip code), the app converts it to a location and then I can display a list of locations within a 50 mile radius from the user?

Comment: search on SO and google, you will find tons of code.

Answer (score 1):

you need to use Geocoder which is a class that's provides multiple functions, you should read about that more at the this site

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/location/Geocoder.html

http://developer.android.com/training/location/display-address.html